# Hide required field of info path section?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

How to hide required field in info path form section. I created the form based on their sections and each section has two required fields. I need to hide each required field when user got submit the item in there section ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden checkbox for each section. Add action rule for submit button (or what you use)

If item was submitted -> make checkbox value true.

And formatting rule for required field

If checkbox value is true -> hide this control

Comment: Right, But my problem is, even if,  I hide the control, still I'm not able to submit the item. Because the required field got stuck me

Comment: @Sara Explain please what do you mean by 'submit the item'?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late answer...

Don't use the required option in this case, but make use of rules. Make the submit button based on rules (not submit) handled. Add rules to check your field on that button and at last when all valid: add submit rule of your form.